# Threading in java

Tags: java

I have created a one child thread and now i want to send some message from child thread to main thread. how can i do this?

Comment: What have you already tried? There are many ways and there's no problem with it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by message? Java threads communicate using shared memory, not message passing. Of course, you can emulate message passing using shared memory. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 7):

In the Thread you created, you will need a reference to the thread you are trying to send the message (method call) to.

I.E.

MainClass.java:

```
public class MainClass implements Runnable
{
    private Queue<String> internalQueue;
    private boolean keepRunning;

    public MainClass()
    {
        keepRunning = true;
        internalQueue = new Queue<String>();
    }

    public void queue(String s)
    {
        internalQueue.add(s);
        this.notify();
    }

    public void run()
    {
         // main thread

         // create child thread
         Runnable r = new YourThread(this);
         new Thread().start(r);

         // process your queue
         while (keepRunning) {
             // check if there is something on your queue
             // sleep
             this.wait();
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       MainClass mc = new MainClass();
       mc.run();
    }
}
```

YourThread.java

```
public class YourThread implements Runnable
{
    private MainClass main;

    public YourThread(MainClass c)
    {
         this.main = c;
    }

    public void run()
    {
         // your thread starts here
         System.out.println("Queue a message to main thread");
         main.queue("Hi from child!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Callable` interface instead of `Runnable`

Comment: +1. I am surprised that this answer is not more upvoted. Go for futures and use thread pools. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent-child relationship between threads.

A thread can spawn another thread, and once spawned, the 2 threads are independent from each other.

Please let us know what you mean by *send a message*. That can encompass a wide range of use cases, and each has its best implementations.

For example, if you want to synchronize 2 threads, you can go ahead and use a simple wait / notify mechanism. For this, you will have to share an object between the 2.

If you want to compute a value in the spawned thread and pass it back, then you can use queues. But you will have to also tell us more about how the execution of the 2 threads is related so that we can suggest the appropriate way to implement it. (Such as producer-consumer mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

Used Priority queue as the object on which the parent (Main thread) and child thread communicate.
**Definition of the child runnable**

```
class CommunicationThead implements Runnable{
    Queue<String> commQueue=null; 
    CommunicationThead(Queue<String> q){
        super();
        this.commQueue=q;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("child :interuppted on sleep");
        }
        synchronized(commQueue){
            if(commQueue!=null)
            {
                commQueue.add("Yo");
                System.out.println("message added by child");
            }
            commQueue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling the child runnable (called in the main())**
the main thread waits till it receives a message from the child thread

```
Queue<String> q=new PriorityQueue<String>();
Thread child=new Thread(new CommunicationThead(q));
child.start();
boolean msgReceived=true;
while(msgReceived){
    synchronized(q){
        if(q.isEmpty())
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("parent: queue empty | parent waiting");
                q.wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("parent wait interrupted");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("parent found message :"+q.poll());
            msgReceived=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyInterface delegate;

    public void setDelegate(MyInterface delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    // this will be performed in a background thread
    public void doStuff() {

        Future<String> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<String>() {

            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return "hello world";
            }
        });

        delegate.handleResponse(future.get());
    }
}

public interface MyInterface {
    void handleResponse(String value);
}

public class MainClass implements MyInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.setDelegate(this);
        myClass.doStuff();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(String value) {

        // this will be on the main thread
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```